# bug "App on Facebook" auto redirect to website

Tags: facebook

I created an "App on Facebook" and enter my website URL at the Canvas URL.

I can see my website within the Facebook app http://apps.facebook.com/abc (example url) for months.

During recent routine check on my  creation, I found that the Facebook app auto redirect the browser to my website.

I want to view my website from Facebook app http://apps.facebook.com/abc and not redirect to my website.

Any advise?

Comment: You sure that the "website with facebook login" is disabled?

Comment: Good day All,

I had found the bug, the problem is verify and confirm is due to Facebook App and GTranslate.

GTranlate info can be obtain from http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/languages/automatic-translations/4823.

I confirm the problem by enable and disable the GTranslate a few times and each time I refresh the Facebook App to see the page will be automatically redirect or not.

Have a nice day..

Eric Leow.